# Yii framework reset defaultScope

Tags: yii, default-scope

In Yii framework,
how can I disable `defaultScope` ?

I tried with `resetScope(false)` and `resetScope(true)`
but to no avail.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: if you can't avoid using that function, just set some scope after it

Comment: Hi @tinybyte I tried that as well but somehow the default scope is always getting added.

Comment: @tinybyte public function defaultScope() {
        $t = $this->getTableAlias(false, false);
        return ['condition' => "`$t`.`status`= 1" ];
    }
 
    public function scopes() {
        $t = $this->getTableAlias(false, false);
        return [
                'displayOff' => ['condition' => "`$t`.`status` = 2 "],
               ];
    　　　}
 
 I am using it like.
 XXX::model()->resetScope(true)->displayOff();
 
 but the QUERY fired is 
 
 select * from XXX Where XXX.status = 1 and XXX.status = 2;

Comment: which version of yii are you using http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#resetScope-detail from documentation it is available since 1.1.2. Please update your question with your yii version.

Comment: thank you for your comment.. I checked the Yii version and apparently its 1.1.15 which is lower than 1.1.2.. But I am just curious.. I checked the sourcode for resetScope function for 1.1.2 (mentioned in docs) and 1.1.15 which I had.. and it seems same .. so my question is where is the change ???? and why is it not working??

Comment: It would help if you added the code for your model and your call to `resetScope` in the question. Look at [the page for MVCE](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#query-detail) for more information

Answer (score 0):

you can disable defaultScode by overriding `defaultScope()` method and returning empty array.

```
public function defaultScope()
{
    return array();
}
```

Comment: I cant do that.. because then I would have to update the code at many places.. what I want it that defaultScope be available for all queries accept the one's for which I reset the scope.

Comment: just do it in a super class.